# Application Loadbalancer - Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk with Application Load-balancer and I'd like to put multiple path patterns into the config.

Any ideas how ?

Comma or space delimeter doesn't work.

config:

`option_settings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:80:
    Protocol: HTTP
    Rules: signuphttp
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:signuphttp:
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:elbv2:listenerrule:signuphttp:
    PathPatterns: /signup/*
    Priority: 1
    Process: signuphttp`

I'm using EB Cli.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

It's done by creating separate rules, then referencing them in the listener:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elbv2:listener:80:
    Protocol: HTTP
    Rules: signuphttp,other
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:signuphttp:
    Port: '80'
    Protocol: HTTP
  aws:elbv2:listenerrule:signuphttp:
    PathPatterns: /signup/*
    Priority: 1
    Process: signuphttp
  aws:elbv2:listenerrule:other:
    PathPatterns: /other/*
    Priority: 1
    Process: signuphttp
```